# Evaluating $ \lim_{ n\to \infty}{\left ( \frac{1\cdot n+2\cdot(n-1)+3\cdot(n-2)+\dots+n\cdot1}{1^3+2^3+\dots+n^3}+1 \right )}^{n}$

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

$$ \lim_{ n\to \infty}{\left ( \frac{1\cdot n+2\cdot(n-1)+3\cdot(n-2)+\dots+n\cdot1}{1^3+2^3+\dots+n^3}+1 \right )}^{n}$$

The main problem that I am facing is the inability to take out $\frac{1}{n}$ common out of the summation expression. As far as I know, we generally take $\frac{1}{n}$ common and we convert it into a definite integral ($\frac{1}{n}$ being dx). Moreover the exponent makes it more complex. [image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UihE5.jpg)

Comment: Hint : the sums $\sum_{k=1}^n k, \sum_{k=1}^n k^2, \sum_{k=1}^n k^3$ can be computed explicitely. Use this to find a closed expression for your sequence

Comment: Thank you! I guess i was constantly thinking to convert it into an integral and that's why couldn't see this simple solution. After the closed expression it transforms into a simple problem of limits.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(n+1-k) = (n+1)\sum_{k=1}^{n}k -\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2 = \frac{(n+1)^2 n}{2}-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=\frac{(n+2)(n+1)n}{6}$$

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^3 = \frac{(n+1)^2 n^2}{4} $$

hence you are looking for the value of the limit

$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{2(n+2)}{3(n+1) n}\right)^n $$
which is $e^{2/3}$.

Comment: Yep couldn't see the simple way :). Thank you